# Check if a number ends in 00 or not

Tags: javascript

I want to increase my minutes var everytime the seconds var reaches '00' in javascript.

So for instance 
Don't increase it when it is 82,761,912
But when it is 82,762,000

How can I check for this? I tried:

`if(Math.floor(seconds) == seconds)`

and

`If(seconds % 1 != 0)`

But neither of them produced the correct results.

Comment: Have you tried `endsWith()` ?

Comment: You do realize that there are not 100 seconds in a minute, right?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes I do, but i temporarily forgot! So I guess I could just `seconds % 60` instead?

Comment: Yes indeed, `% 60`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks, sorry for the idiocy.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `test`

```
  /0{2}$/
```

- `0{2}` - Match 0 two time
- `$` - End of string

```js
let testZeros = (str) => /0{2}$/.test(str)

console.log(testZeros(12345))
console.log(testZeros(123450))
console.log(testZeros(1234500))
```

Or you can do

```js
let testZeros = (num) => num % 100 === 0

console.log(testZeros(12345))
console.log(testZeros(123450))
console.log(testZeros(1234500))
```

We have `endsWith` also

```js
let testZeros = (str) => (str +'').endsWith('00')

console.log(testZeros(12345))
console.log(testZeros(123450))
console.log(testZeros(1234500))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you're looking for a modulo 100 operation, but since you're dealing with seconds and minutes, you actually need a modulo 60 operation:

```js
const test = (seconds) => !(seconds % 60);

console.log(test(82761912)); // false
console.log(test(82762020)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second option should work with some tweaking. Say,

```
    if(seconds % 100 == 0){
    //increment minutes here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if(seconds % 100 == 0)
 alert("end with 00");
else
 alert("Not end with 00");
```